# Stock balance maintaining in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to calculate an output column which is the difference of two
other columns in the query output; the first column is an aggregate of
items in stock, while the second column is an aggregate of items which
have been used. The third column should should be the difference of the
two values so I can then output all three columns in a table.

I would like to know the remaining stock after making the purchasing and sales in rails way.

Please find below the screenshot for the reference;

[Screenshot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2l92.png)

For purchase table,

stockings_controller.rb

```
class StockingsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_stocking, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /Stockings
  # GET /deldetails.json
  def index
    @stockings = Stocking.all
  end

  def import
    Stocking.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to stockings_url, notice: "Stockings imported."
  end

  # GET /Stockings/1
  # GET /Stockings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /Stockings/new
  def new
    @stocking = Stocking.new
  end

  # GET /stockings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /Stockings
  # POST /Stockings.json
  def create
    @stocking = Stocking.new(stocking_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @stocking.save
        format.html { redirect_to @stocking, notice: 'Stocking was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @stocking }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @stocking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /Stockings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /stockings/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @stocking.update(stocking_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @stocking, notice: 'Stocking was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @stocking }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @stocking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /stockings/1
  # DELETE /stockings/1.json
  def destroy
    @stocking.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to stockings_url, notice: 'Stocking was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_stocking
      @stocking = Stocking.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def stocking_params
      params.require(:stocking).permit(:slno, :category, :articleno, :description, :color, :quantity, :rprice, :total, :cartonno )
    end
  end
```

stocking.rb

class Stocking < ActiveRecord::Base

```
def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        Stocking.create! row.to_hash
    end
end
```

end

index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

        <div class="table-responsive myTable">

            <table class="table listing text-center">
                <tr class="tr-head">
                    <td>SLNO</td>
                    <td>CATEGORY</td>
                    <td>ARTICLE NO</td>
                    <td>DESCRIPTION</td>
                    <td>COLOR</td>
                    <td>QUANTITY</td>
                    <td>RETAIL PRICE</td>
                    <td>TOTAL</td>
                    <td>CARTON NO</td>
                </tr>

                <% @stockings.each do |stocking| %>
                <tr class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

                    <td class="col-1">
                        <%= stocking.slno %>
                    </td><td class="col-1">
                    <%= stocking.articleno %>
                </td><td class="col-1">
                <%= stocking.category %>
            </td><td class="col-1">
            <%= stocking.description %>
        </td><td class="col-1">
        <%= stocking.color %>
    </td><td class="col-1">
    <%= stocking.quantity %>
</td><td class="col-1">
<%= stocking.rprice %>
</td><td class="col-1">
<%= stocking.total %>
</td><td class="col-1">
<%= stocking.cartonno %>
</td>
</tr>
<% end %>

</table>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New stocking', new_stocking_path %>


<!--           |=== HERE  -->
<a href="#" class="toggle-form">...</a>

<div id="test">
    <h2>Import StOCKS</h2>
    <%= form_tag import_stockings_path, multipart: true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
    <% end %>
</div>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#test").hide();

    //    | === HERE
    $("a.toggle-form").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("div#test").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

I have prepared the purchased table as above but unable to tackle the idea of handling remaining stock.

I am in a confusion that do I need to create the same for sales etc
or do I choose some other way.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you share some portions of your code? We could tell you this is the way to go, which may not resonate with your current implementation and that would result in more confusion

Comment: Thank you for your prompt  reply. I put some code as per your request. Please review and guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the remaining stock in the following way, remaining stock = purchased quantity - sold quantity to customers which are designated as cus1, cus2 and so on and so my index view would be as below;

index.html.erb

`<td class="col-2"><%= stock = stock.quantity - stock.cus1 - stock.cus2 %></td>`

In this way I got the actual remaining stock.